# Share variables between websites

Tags: c#, razor

I have two websites that I'd like to share information. Not database-like information, but more some fixed values to set some settings.

Right now I'm using AppState variables because I hoped, that they were shared in the entire apppool and not just under the same domain.

Of course I can set the same Session/AppState variables on both websites, but for maintaining and performance reasons I'd like to change/get the values only one place.

How do I do that best?

I'm aware that cookies can be shared between domain/subdomain (even though I've never got that to work very well) - but I believe the user can change the value in the cookie (right?), and I don't want that.

Thanks.

Comment: Are they both running on the same host?  Take your pick of IPC technology otherwise use REST or SOAP

Comment: The SQL session manager would do the trick

Comment: @MickyD I'm not familiar with IPC. Can you give me a simple SOAP example?

Comment: @musab That sounds like a way to go. My MSSQL is on a shared server, I believe that can be a problem with setup/installation?